# How to make a multi-select lightswitch ComboBox and how to filter a query with this

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I need to filter a Lightswitch query with a multi select combobox. I can build a wpf control to make the combobox , but I don't know how to filter.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Ok sorry, is my first post ..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Heres how I did it.
First create a separate query on your table. It doesnt have to be different than the original. The reason is the combobox will be populated by the query, so if the query is filtered, then so will the combobox items and we dont want that. Next, make sure you turn of paging for that query or you'll only get 45(the default value) items in the combobox.

Next you need your custom control. I made a simple silverlight combobox.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightControlLibrary.SilverlightComboBoxControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
Height="23" 
Width="180">   

    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180"
          Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="ModuleIDFilterCB" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Screen.ADDEDQUERY, Mode=OneWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ADDEDQUERYCOLUMN"      
          SelectedItem="{Binding Screen.LOCALPROPERTY, Mode=TwoWay}"
          />
</UserControl>
```

From your created query you populate your combobox with the "ItemsSource" property and the "DiplayMemberPath". The source being the query and the path the name of the column.

Now the good part. Create a local propety of the type of the column you need to be filtered. create a parameter in the query window for the table you need filtered. Make sure this is NOT the same query you used to populate the Combobox! Map the parameter to the property.

The query with its parameter mapped, is now filtered by the local property you created. And as you have noticed in the XAML the last line sets the combobox's selected item to the local property. make sure you use the "Screen." path for your query and your property and make sure the selectedItems binding is in "twoWay" mode.

Then it should work.